# Relational database regarding two tables

Tags: mysql, database

Is it advisable to have table A having two foreign keys from table B? My thinking is that if one of the foreign key in table A is a primary key, then there is no need to add additional foreign key in table A.

Comment: What are you trying to model with above? Perhaps if you share that, we can advise better

Comment: This sounds like a conceptual problem with your structural design.  If a row in t1 references a row in t2 then the row in t1 (by definition) references all the attributes of the row in t2.  Otherwise, you're copying attributes from one table to another and setting yourself up for update anomalies, or your primary key in t2 should be multi-column, or there's something else unusual in your design that might be better handled with a junction table or better normalization.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I could see it possibly being valid. If table B has a foreign key to A's Primary key, you are saying every B must point to some A. but you could also have a foreign key to a nullable field in A, meaning A must exist and have data for the second field in your key.

Comment: I was helped. Thanks to all those who assisted